# How I can send custom parameters through java?

Tags: java, parameters, logic, key-value

Suppose I want to send following parameters :

```
key1: value1,
key2: value2
```

But currently I can't decide what will be there at place of key1,key2
That may be any string. key1 may be city,key2 may be code. Or key 1 may be companyName and key 2 is domain. So how can I set any custom unknown parametrs in method of java? Consider that I know total number of parameters and data type of their values, but can't determine their exact keys now. How to implement it in java?

Comment: `Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();` and then `map.put(k, v);` as you see fit?

Comment: Ok, Thanks.trying the same..

Comment: If i understand correctly, you are stating that your key values can be of any type, so you can just set it to Object type, 
(also, as you haven't specified the datatype of values so you can you Object type if you are going to use int, String or multiple datatypes there).

`Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 0):

You can send an array of objects in your method:

```
Object[] myObjects = new Object[2];
myObjects[0] = "This is a string";
myObjects[1] = 5;

myMethod(myObjects);


public void myMethod(Object[] myObjects){
    // DoSomethingOverHere
}
```

If you only have Strings you can do the same but specify an array of Strings instead of objects. If you use objects, make sure to check the instance of the objects before using it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you mean to achieve is a method that can accept any type of argument and still do the work.

Below is the approach I would use:
Lets say you want to use myMethod:

```
  class MainClass  {

  public Object myMethod(Object A,Object B)
  {
      Object C=(Object) (A.toString()+","+B.toString());

      System.out.println(C.toString());

      return C;

  }
}
```

And you can call it with any type of parameters:

```
public class TesterClass {


    MainClass mainClass=new MainClass();
    mainClass.myMethod(123, "PQR");
    mainClass.myMethod(123.00, "PQR");
    mainClass.myMethod(123.00, 123);
    mainClass.myMethod(new int[]{1,2,3}, "PQR");


}
```

Your output will be:

```
123,PQR

123.0,PQR

123.0,123

[I@659e0bfd,PQR
```

last one is array, you can manipulate its processing)